# ASP.NET web site hosted on Azure is authenticating for every 3-4 minutes in the background

Tags: asp.net, azure, wif, session-timeout, azure-worker-roles

i m working on a azure asp.net website. i m using microsoft identity foundation in azure for authentication using the live id.

when i open a form and enter some data, and leave it for some time, then the page tries to authenticate after 3-4 minutes in the background.

CanI avoid this using settings in web.config?

Answer (score 2):

Well, by default it's going to obey the lifetime specified in the security token (i.e. `ValidFrom`/`ValidTo`). So if the IP has given you a token with a short validity lifespan then you have no choice but to request a new one after that window has expired. The only other way to affect this is to make it short either by configuring `<sessionTimeoutTokenRequirement lifetime="...timespan..." />` or via custom logic in the `SessionSecurityToken[Created|Received]` event handlers of the `SessionAuthenticationModule`. Again, this is only something the RP does to *shorten* the lifetime... it can't ever extend it beyond the original window from the IP.